# Don't work WPML dropdown on front end part

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I installed WPML plugin setup change button on top menu list, set DROPDOWN option
[image]

But on front-end view it show's just list of languages
[image]

Code on browser looks good, I mean ul li structure and so on, but something break styles of dropdown.

Comment: It might be better to open a support ticket with WPML as there are hundred of reasons why it might not be working.

Comment: it seems js is not loading, can you please check errors in console of your browser